# UDP protocol support in common web browser

Tags: networking, udp

Entering "udp://host:666" in the location bar doesn't work very well. Is there any work-around for sending a single "empty" datagram to a host using an ordinary web browser?

The response is no issue since the use case I'm think about is port knocking ("http://host:666" doesn't work well since browsers tend to repeat the request if there is no response, thus violating the designated knock sequence).

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is a TCP protocol. A web browser is the wrong tool.

From a quick google, http://netcat.sourceforge.net/ came up. It might be able to send that UDP for you.

Comment: If jonas is running Windows, you could also mention http://joncraton.org/blog/46 which hosts a Win32 port.